# Is a root, an octave, followed by a 5th a EsusAdd5

Tags: guitar, theory, chords, chord-theory

If you have a Root - Octave - 5th, does this become a EsusAdd5 even though you don't play the first 5th in the scale or is just a different voicing/shape for Esus?

Comment: There's no 'sus' in this chord, and the octave displacement doesn't affect the chord symbol - not ALL information about a chord can be conveyed in a symbol, that's why we have notation! It's just E5.

Comment: What is suspended here? All you really have is I and V.

Comment: @Stinkfoot to be honest I had no idea I was using a chord identifier and that was one of the top ones that came up. I didn't think it was, but it was the only kinda hint I had at the time.

Comment: FYI - the simplest from of a suspended chord takes the form 1-4-5 - for example C-F-G . it is a chord with no 3rd and is called 'suspended' because the 4 - F is considered relatively dissonant in that context and should be resolved with a 3 but it isn't - it is 'suspended' without resolution. 100 years ago this was not considered a 'valid' chord - but it has slowly come into common use and today, at least in jazz and rock, a suspended chord is considered a 'valid' chord type. (There are other forms of suspended chords as well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a variation of a power chord if something like this is what you are talking about:

```
X:1
L:1/1
M:
K:E
V:1 clef=treble
"E5"[E' E B] |
%
```

The octave notes appear in does not affect what you call a chord in general and this only has a root and a 5th. To be a sus you need a root, perfect 4th and perfect 5th (or root, major 2nd and perfect 5th for sus2). An example of a sus and sus2 is below:

```
X:1
L:1/2
M:
K:E
V:1 clef=treble
"Esus"[E A B] "Esus2"[E ^F B]|
%
```